# How to query Grakn with Java?

Tags: java, vaticle-typedb

I went through the documentation of Java api to query Grakn database.

```
Grakn.Transaction readTransaction = session.transaction(GraknTxType.READ);
GetQuery query = Graql.match(var("p").isa("person")).limit(10).get();
Stream<ConceptMap> answers = query.withTx(readTransaction).stream();
answers.forEach(answer -> System.out.println(answer.get("p").id()));
```

It's printing id, but I want to see the data, the name associated with the person. I want to see the content inside the result. It's simply showing id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answers provided as the result of a Graql query, is a collection of the variables (and their values) as you have specified them in the query itself.

In this case, to get the `name` of instances of `person`, you'd include it in the query like so:

```java
GetQuery query = Graql.match(var("p").isa("person").has("name", var("n"))).limit(10).get();
```

The Graql equivalent being `match $p isa person, has name $n; get;`.

Now you can use the methods available in the [Concept API](http://dev.grakn.ai/docs/concept-api/overview) to retrieve information available on each variable.

In this case, variable `n` holds an `attribute` and you'd want to retrieve its `value()`, like so:

```java
answers.forEach(answer -> System.out.println(answer.get("n").asAttribute().value()))
```